# Use UIButton to toggle label text multiple times

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to create a button that when pressed will change the label text to a different text each time it is pressed, about five times. For example, when the button is pressed once, the label says "1"; when the same button is pressed again, the label says "2"; and so forth. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to do a little more studying of iOS.  This is elementary.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am overthinking this. I can change the label by pushing the button once, but the same button to change a label multiple times? I was thinking of a switch function combined with UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSArray with all the strings/texts that you require to show in the label text... make a IBAction method and have it go through the array index everytime user taps the UIButton.

Comment: If you don't need to loop it you could also just put everything in an array and pop off (remove) the 0th element each time so you don't need to keep track of what index you're on.

Answer (score 0):

If your just counting numbers up, then use something like this in the button pressed IBAction:

```
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int btnNum = [btn.titleLabel.text integerValue];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", btnNum++] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```